# Host not showing in ARP even after broadcast

Tags: vlan, ip-address, arp, mac-address

serverfault community.

**What I would like:** to determine the current IP of a host (a networked camera to be specific)

**What I have:** its MAC, its previously documented hostname and IP

**What I have done**: ping the IP, ping the hostname, check the DHCP leases, check the DNS records, check the ARP table, ping the subnet broadcast then check the ARP table, try the IP in a browser

**The short story:** This device was previously configured, then an office relocation took it out of the network. I would like to reintegrate it, ideally with its previous configuration intact.

**The details:** The camera was configured as 10.25.22.37 (or .38), on a /24 subnet, on a particular VLAN. It has a documented hostname. I have access to all the network devices it might feasibly be going through. I have confirmed that it is on the same VLAN as my laptop, and according to the documented configuration, it should be on the same subnet as well.

**The problem:** I still cannot find any trace of it, other than its MAC showing on the correct port of a managed switch.

Comment: Some ideas: Run Wireshark on your laptop and see if you find something the camera spits out... and/or mirror the camera's apparent port and see what's going on there...

Comment: I would analyze the network traffic the device originates after power cycling it. Usually you can figure out from that what it's doing.

Comment: You said you checked the dhcp *leases*, but did you also check the logs? Maybe it's trying to acquire an address in an entirely different network through a dhcp forwarder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, my superiors required a quick resolution and I had to reset it and start from scratch. But thank you all for your helpful suggestions.